# using element of one div from another div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a file, and there is a fragment for navbar. In the navbar, we have listItems, and based on the click of those listItems, we plan to open another subnavigationbar below it.

To achieve this, I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5">
<body>
    <div>
        <div th:fragment="navbar">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03"
                    aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item active"><a id="movies"
                            th:class="(${#httpServletRequest.requestURI}=='/movies') ? 'nav-link active' : 'nav-link'"
                            href="#subNavbarId">Movies</a></li>  <!-- href fails -->
                        <li class="nav-item"><a id="hr"
                            th:class="(${#httpServletRequest.requestURI}=='/info') ? 'nav-link active' : 'nav-link'"
                            href="/info">Info</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
                        Logged in: <span sec:authentication="name"></span>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var projects = document.getElementById("movies");
                var subNavBar = document.getElementById("subNavbarId"); //Failure
                projects.addEventListener("click", function() {
                    subNavBar.style = "display:block;"
                })
            </script>
        </div>

        <div class = "subNavClass" id="subNavbarId" th:fragment="subnavbar" style="display: none;">
            <nav id="navbar-nav ms-auto" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg"
                style="background-color: #F5F5F5;">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <a class="navbar-brand px-5"></a>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a id="subnavbar-content"
                            href="/movieList"> movieList</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                var subNavBar = document.getElementById("subNavbarId");
                subNavBar.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
                    subNavBar.style = "display:none;"
                })
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to have a scenario, where I click the "movie" on the navbar, and I get a subnavbar displayed with movieList. Similarly, when I click somewhere outside, the subnavbar fades away.

Guide me here.
PS: total noob

Comment: Could you try to explain the concrete issue you are facing and what you have tried to solve it? This snippet seems to be broken as there's no element with a id `projects` in it...

Comment: @AndreNuechter, I have made the changes. I am trying to access the __subNavBar__ from the __navBar__ div. The requirement is to have a  subNavBar which is responsive, currently I am doing it statically

Answer (score 1):

your `subNavBar.style = "display:block;"` looks wrong.

it should be `subNavBar.style.display = "block";`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/), you can use a dropdown :

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Action
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">An action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

By the way, avoid changing css with javascript. You can make a css class and toggle it. Because you use Bootstrap, you can toggle the `d-none` provided class :
`subNavBar.classList.toggle("d-none");`